Cart Items Container Not Scrolling Properly on Mobile
I’m working on a web layout where I need the .cart-items-container to occupy the remaining space above the .cart-rest-details section. The .cart-items-container should be scrollable if its content overflows, and the .cart-rest-details should remain fixed at the bottom of the viewport. But I’m encountering issues with the layout on mobile devices.
Here I've attached my codebase.


.cart-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cart-items-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cart-items {
  padding: 8px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 2px solid orange
}

.cart-rest-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .cart-items-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .cart-items {
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-height: none;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cart-container">
    <div class="cart-items-container">
      <h1>Cart Items</h1>

      <div class="cart-items">
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 5</p>
        <p>Item 6</p>
        <p>Item 7</p>
        <p>Item 8</p>
        <p>Item 9</p>
        <p>Item 10</p>
        <p>Item 11</p>
        <p>Item 12</p>
        <p>Item 13</p>
        <p>Item 14</p>
        <p>Item 15</p>
        <p>Item 16</p>
        <p>Item 17</p>
        <p>Item 18</p>
        <p>Item 19</p>
        <p>Item 20</p>
        <p>Item 21</p>
        <p>Item 22</p>
        <p>Item 23</p>
        <p>Item 24</p>
        <p>Item 25</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cart-rest-details">
      <p>Description 1</p>
      <p>Description 2</p>
      <p>Description 3</p>
      <p>Description 4</p>
      <p>Description 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



On mobile devices, the .cart-items-container does not properly fill the remaining space above .cart-rest-details, and the .cart-items section does not scroll as expected.
Current behavior:

Expected behavior:


I've added resize: both on your .cart-container so you can drag from bottom right to see how this adapts:


body {
  margin: 1vh;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.cart-container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
  height: 98vh;
}

.cart-items-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.cart-items {
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  height: 50px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.cart-rest-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cart-container">
    <div class="cart-items-container">
      <h1>Cart Items</h1>

      <div class="cart-items">
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 5</p>
        <p>Item 6</p>
        <p>Item 7</p>
        <p>Item 8</p>
        <p>Item 9</p>
        <p>Item 10</p>
        <p>Item 11</p>
        <p>Item 12</p>
        <p>Item 13</p>
        <p>Item 14</p>
        <p>Item 15</p>
        <p>Item 16</p>
        <p>Item 17</p>
        <p>Item 18</p>
        <p>Item 19</p>
        <p>Item 20</p>
        <p>Item 21</p>
        <p>Item 22</p>
        <p>Item 23</p>
        <p>Item 24</p>
        <p>Item 25</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cart-rest-details">
      <p>Description 1</p>
      <p>Description 2</p>
      <p>Description 3</p>
      <p>Description 4</p>
      <p>Description 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



The flexbox algorithm treats your max-height as a preferred height and won't shrink below it, so setting a super low height and allowing flex grow to do the magic for us should yield the desired result

Try adding min-height: 0; to .cart-items-container.
Because by default, a child of flexbox will not shrink below min-content (which is determined by its child content) even with flex-shrink set to a non-zero value. By setting min-height: 0 overrides this behavior that allows it to shrink properly, thus the scroll bar will appear as expected.


.cart-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cart-items-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* added */
  min-height: 0;
}

.cart-items {
  padding: 8px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 2px solid orange
}

.cart-rest-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .cart-items-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .cart-items {
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-height: none;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cart-container">
    <div class="cart-items-container">
      <h1>Cart Items</h1>

      <div class="cart-items">
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 5</p>
        <p>Item 6</p>
        <p>Item 7</p>
        <p>Item 8</p>
        <p>Item 9</p>
        <p>Item 10</p>
        <p>Item 11</p>
        <p>Item 12</p>
        <p>Item 13</p>
        <p>Item 14</p>
        <p>Item 15</p>
        <p>Item 16</p>
        <p>Item 17</p>
        <p>Item 18</p>
        <p>Item 19</p>
        <p>Item 20</p>
        <p>Item 21</p>
        <p>Item 22</p>
        <p>Item 23</p>
        <p>Item 24</p>
        <p>Item 25</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cart-rest-details">
      <p>Description 1</p>
      <p>Description 2</p>
      <p>Description 3</p>
      <p>Description 4</p>
      <p>Description 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




I can't see .cart-items-container at all in this example

@ZachJensz try run in full page and turn on mobile simulator in devtools

so this code will simply fail to work on small screen sizes? Is that the decision you have made?

@ZachJensz OP never mentioned how it should look like on a device that only has height of 200px (default preview size of SO editor) - there's no way to show all the content in this small height. I'm only addressing why the content is not shrinking as OP was expecting. Sure you could hard code its height to 50px
and all other changes you have made to make it visible in a small height like how you did in your apporach, but that's changing OP's design and is beyond the topic of this post.
